# Каким образом можно выбирать значения заполняемого поля

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

У меня есть таблица в которой есть правила:

rules

| RULE_ID | RESULT | RUN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rule_one | 65 | 4567 |
| rule_two | 0 | 4567 |
| rule_one | 635 | 1234 |
| rule_two | 20 | 1234 |

Есть таблица в которой есть значения:

applications

| APPLICATION | SOMEVAL | RUN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| app_one | 65 | 1234 |
| app_two | 0 | 1234 |
| app_three | 625 | 4567 |
| app_four | 43 | 4567 |

```
CASE when cw.liq_min_prepay_pct is null and ds.rule_id = 1 or ds.result != 0) then ds.result END AS liq_min_prepay_pct
```

Я хочу сделать join, который должен сделать такую выборку:

| RUN_ID | APPLICATION | rule_one | rule_two |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | app_one | 635 | 1234 |
| 4567 | app_two | 65 | 0 |

Была идея сделать так:

```
    select run_id,APPLICATION, rule_one, rule_two  
    from rules left join applications
    on rules.run_id = applications.run_id
    where rule_id in ('rule_one', 'rule_two' );
```

Однако в итоге получаю что то вроде этого:

| RUN_ID | APPLICATION | rule_one | rule_two |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | app_one | 635 | 1234 |
| 1234 | app_one | 65 | 0 |
| 4567 | app_two | 635 | 1234 |
| 4567 | app_two | 0 | 1234 |

Comment: MySQL <> OracleDB. Уберите ошибочный тег.

Comment: *join, который должен сделать такую выборку* Обычный PIVOT. Используйте условное агрегирование.